# Today's date without time aspect

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently trying to achieve an output which gives today's date without time.

I currently have the code

```
import datetime as date
today = date.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-5%d")
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: your example doesn't contain any time

Comment: The output is providing the current date and time, I only want it to display date

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
from time import strftime
print(strftime('%b %d, %Y'))   #or use '%Y-%m-%d'
```